# Extra pages for a magazine

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, vocabulary

In some special days, e.g. the days before the New Year, newspapers and magazines give away some extra pages or even an special magazine associated with those days, or related to the year passed. What are these extra pages called?

Comment: Rob has your answer. The following may also be helpful for you... You know those (incredibly annoying) advertisements that are separate small pieces of paper which just sort of "sit" in the magazine?  (They are often return coupons, etc.) In the trade they are called "blow-ins" because the machine that inserts them works in that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a *supplement*. From NOAD:

**supplement**
*noun* |ˈsəpləmənt|
1 something that completes or enhances something else when added to it : *the handout is a supplement to the official manual*.
• a substance taken to remedy the deficiencies in a person's diet : *multivitamin supplements*.
• a part added to a book to provide further or corrected information but separate from the main body of the text.
• **a separate section, esp. a color magazine, added to a newspaper or periodical**.

[Emphasis added by me on final entry]